# Kotlin Creating List<List<Map<String, String>>>

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I am trying to return List<List<Map<String, String>>> from a function in kotlin. I'm new to kotlin.

**Edit1**

Here's how I am attempting to to this

```
val a = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(mutableMapOf<String, String>()))
```

The problem with the above variable is, I am unable to figure out how to insert data into this variable. I tried with this:

```
val a = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(mutableMapOf<String, String>()))
val b = mutableListOf(mutableMapOf<String, String>())
val c = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
c.put("c", "n")
b.add(c)
a.add(b)
```

This is giving me:

```
[[{}], [{}, {c=n}]]
```

What I want is [[{c=n}]]

Can someone tell me how I can insert data into it?

The end goal I am trying to achieve is to store data in the form of **List<List<Map<String, String>>>**

**EDIT 2**

The function for which I am trying to write this dat structure:

```
fun processReport(file: Scanner): MutableList<List<Map<String, String>>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<List<Map<String, String>>>()
    val columnNames = file.nextLine().split(",")
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        val record = mutableListOf<Map<String, String>>()
        val rowValues = file.nextLine()
            .replace(",(?=[^\"]*\"[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*$)".toRegex(), "")
            .split(",")
        for (i in rowValues.indices) {
            record.add(mapOf(columnNames[i] to rowValues[i]))
            print(columnNames[i] + " : " + rowValues[i] + "   ")
        }
        result.add(record)
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use mutable data structures. You can define it like this:

```
fun main() {
    val a = listOf(listOf(mapOf("c" to "n")))
    println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
[[{c=n}]]
```

---

If you wanted to use mutable data structures and add the data later, you could do it like this:

```
fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    val innerList = mutableListOf<Map<String, String>>()
    val outerList = mutableListOf<List<Map<String, String>>>()

    map["c"] = "n"
    innerList.add(map)
    outerList.add(innerList)

    println(outerList)
}
```

The output is the same, although the lists and maps are mutable.

---

In response to the 2nd edit. Ah, you're parsing a CSV. You shouldn't try to do that yourself, but you should use a library. Here's an example using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

```
fun processReport(file: File): List<List<Map<String, String>>> {
    val parser = CSVParser.parse(file, Charset.defaultCharset(), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader())
    return parser.records.map {
        it.toMap().entries.map { (k, v) -> mapOf(k to v) }
    }
}
```

For the following CSV:

```
foo,bar,baz
a,b,c
1,2,3
```

It produces:

```
[[{foo=a}, {bar=b}, {baz=c}], [{foo=1}, {bar=2}, {baz=3}]]
```

Note that you can simplify it further if you're happy returning a list of maps:

```
fun processReport(file: File): List<Map<String, String>> {
    val parser = CSVParser.parse(file, Charset.defaultCharset(), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader())
    return parser.records.map { it.toMap() }
}
```

Output:

```
[{foo=a, bar=b, baz=c}, {foo=1, bar=2, baz=3}]
```

I'm using `Charset.defaultCharset()` here, but you should change it to whatever character set the CSV is in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I am using this in a loop hence cannot use the first approach you have suggested :) But this helped me get i the right direction so I can properly insert data in list and map without getting any empty entries.

Comment: Instead of using loops and mutable datastructures. You may be able to use the `map` function to do what you want. Difficult to see without your code though. :)

Comment: I added the function for which I am trying to use the data structure. I could not see how would I use `map` to avoid loops. Would definitely like to know :-)

Comment: Ah, you're parsing a CSV. Updated the answer. Good luck ;-)

Comment: How is the "parser.records.map { it.toMap() }" mapping it with the appropriate Key-value pair? I know we can do it like "it.key to it.value", but how so just by "it.toMap()"? Is this something cause of the CSVParser?

Comment: Yes, the CSV parser is handling that automatically because I provided the `withHeader()` option when creating the parser - it knows the first row provides the keys and the current row provides be the values.